# How to keep track of more than 3 fingers in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multi-touch

My mobile game requires sometimes to drag an object with 2 fingers while zooming with the camera using 2 other fingers, which Unity's default touch inputs don't really like..

I've tried tracking each fingers using Touch.fingerid but it goes nuts each time there's more than 2 fingers on screen.
I also wanted to try TouchScript but I couldn't find any example about what I want

Here's what I've tried to code to keep track of fingerIDs using Unity's default touch inputs (which breaks each time there's more than 2 fingers)

```
int n = 0;
int[] cmtBackup = cameraMovementTouchs;
Touch[] allTouches = InputHelper.GetTouches().ToArray();
Touch[] tempTouches = new Touch[cameraMovementTouchs.Length];

for (int y = 0; y < cameraMovementTouchs.Length; y++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < allTouches.Length; i++)
    {
        if (allTouches[i].fingerId == cameraMovementTouchs[y]) 
        { 
            tempTouches[y] = allTouches[i]; 
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < cameraMovementTouchs.Length; i++)
{
    if (tempTouches[i].phase != TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        cmtBackup[n] = cameraMovementTouchs[i];
        n++;
    }

}

cameraMovementTouchs = new int[n];
touches = new Touch[n];

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{ 
    cameraMovementTouchs[i] = cmtBackup[i]; 
    touches[i] = tempTouches[i]; 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your device supports more than 3 fingers? I know my tablet can only go up to five

Comment: Yup, I got up to 10 fingers with another app

Comment: EDIT: My phone's latest update enabled a "three fingers on screen to screenshot" function by itself which limited touch inputs to 3.. Sorry !

Comment: And this is why the removal of physical buttons was a terrible move. Thanks [phone maker]! May as well answer your own question with that one! :)

Answer (score 0):

My phone was limiting the touch inputs due to a "three fingers on screen to screenshot" function of my phone, so the script I posted up here is working !